# Completely stuck on getting a basic a JSON select2 working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-select2

I am close on this but being a javascript / json newbie I am sure I am missing something obvious here.  The JSON select2 example is a bit over the top so I am lost trying to convert it to my simple implementation.

I have a Model (City) with a big list of cities with other associated data etc.  I am aiming for a basic typeahead input where the city / province gets displayed and the id from the City model gets passed in the form.

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#e6').select2
    placeholder: 'Select a City...'
    minimumInputLength: 3
    ajax:
      url: '/cities.json'
      dataType: 'json'
      quietMillis: 250
      data: (query) ->
        { query: query }
      results: (data) ->
        { results: $.map(data, (item) ->
          {
            id: item.id
            text: item.name + ', ' + item.province
          }
        ) }

#     formatResult: formatResult
#     formatSelection: formatSelection
#     initSelection: initSelection

      cache: true

return
```

My JSON is triggering as I can confirm from my logs. For example `http://localhost:3000/cities.json?query=cal` yields:

```
[[1714,"Calais","AB"],[1716,"Calder","SK"],[1717,"Calderbank","SK"],[1731,"Calgary","AB"],[1738,"Calling Lake","AB"],[1739,"Callingwood North","AB"],[1740,"Callingwood South","AB"],[1743,"Calmar","AB"]]
```

Now right off the bat I think this is my issue.  Should this not be:

```
[ id: 1731, name: "Calgary", province: "AB"], etc..?
```

Here is my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { 

      render json: @cities 

    }
end
```

Looking ahead I can see that I could probably have my controller spit out the 'text' values in the "City, Province" format I want too.

So my question(s) are: am I missing something obvious in my JS and / or do I need to fix my JSON and if so how?

Comment: You are returning a list of lists, instead of a list of objects. I'm not familiar enough with RoR to help with that part specifically, but `cities` doesn't appear to contain the equivalent of JSON objects.

Comment: Yes... I found my issue.  I had added a pluck to the end of my Rails control object which produces the array vs. an object.  It works great now.